# Is the word ムキムキ a deliberate visual pun?

Tags: words, etymology, adjectives

I recently learned the word ムキムキ and what instantly struck me was how it appears to be some kind of a visual pun.

ム representing a flexed arm

キ representing a classic barbell

Together they appear to be a set of arms exercising which seems appropriate considering the word means muscular/brawny. Is this just a coincidence?

I have found one [blog post](https://midorixde.exblog.jp/26707302/) which seems to suggests it comes from the German word 'Muskel' but the phonetic translation seems to be quite different.

Comment: FWIW *Mucki* (pl. *Muckis*) is German slang for "muscle(s)", but I like your idea of it being a visual pun much better!

Comment: Interesting. "Muqui" (same pronunciation) is used in Brazilian Portuguese with the same meaning and context.

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider: A friend of mine from Brazil gave me a word-nerd nutshell of how Brazilian Portuguese (`pt_BR`) differs from European Portuguese (`pt_PT`), and one of the main things she described was an influx of vocabulary and other linguistic bits and bobs from all the locals and all the immigrants, including many from Germany.  Presumably _muqui_ in Brazilian Portuguese is a borrowing from German _Mucki_?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi That's probably true! [Wiktionary](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/muque) says nothing, except that the correct spelling is "muque".

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider: Interestingly, the [_Dicionário Brasileiro da Língua Portuguesa_ entry](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/muque/) suggests that it's an internal development from _músculo_, similar to how the German term _Mucki_ derives from _Muskel_.  Parallel evolution, perhaps?

Comment: This is somewhat of a side note, but there are a number of borrowed German words in Japanese which relate to medicine. This is because of cultural exchange between the two countries from the Meiji period onwards, with a number of German physicians being employed in Japan in prestigious positions. Now there are German-origin words like アレルギー (Allergie), ギプス (Gips), ガーゼ (Gaze),  ヘルペス (Herpes), ホルモン(Hormon),  インポ (Impotenz), カプセル (Kapsel), カルテ (Karte), ノイローゼ (Neurose), レントゲン (Röntgen), ワクチン (Vakzin), etc.

Comment: @kandyman, don't forget ヘルツ!  :)  I note that these all derive from academic-register German, as expected for the subject matter.  It seems unlikely that a slang / dialect term would sneak in via the medical route.  As I look again, I find no evidence in German for a singular _Mucki_, only the plural _Muckis_.  See [the Duden entry](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Muckis), for instance.  This may further complicate a proposed German derivation for ムキムキ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on kandyman's answer.

#### Origins of *mukimuki*: probably not German

According to the Shogakukan *Kokugo Dai Jiten* (KDJ) entry [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%90%91%E5%90%91-2086184), the first cited textual instance of a word *mukimuki* is way back in the 700s in the *Man'yōshū* poetry anthology.  This is much older than the German word *Muskel* ("muscle"), of which *Mucki* is a derivation.  Per the **Herkunft** ("Etymology") section in the Duden entry [here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Muskel#herkunft), *Muskel* traces back to Latin *musculus* ("little mouse"), presumably from the way a flexing muscle looks a bit like a small animal moving around.

#### Origins of *mukimuki*: sense development

Again per [the KDJ entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%90%91%E5%90%91-2086184), *mukimuki* meant something more like "each going in whichever facing (*muki*) or direction", and this extended to a sense of "different preferences and inclinations".  We see similar senses listed in the Daijisen and Daijirin entries [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%90%91%E3%81%8D%E5%90%91%E3%81%8D-641095).

So far, none of these list any sense related to "muscular".  We don't find that until we look [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%80%E3%81%8D%E3%82%80%E3%81%8D-641096) in the Daijisen entry for the kana-only spellizang むきむき, or [here](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%80%E3%81%8D%E3%82%80%E3%81%8D) in the Japanese Wiktionary.

I can't find anything directly relevant to how the "muscular" sense arose.  I suspect two possibilities:

- From the oldest sense of "each going in whichever direction", developing from the idea of "able to go whatever way", to "capable / strong" in general, and from there to "muscular".
  This seems less likely, given the sizable semantic (meaning-wise) gap between "each in their own direction" to "muscular".  The KDJ in particular is pretty good about listing historical development where known, and [their entry for 向き向き](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%90%91%E5%90%91-2086184) is missing any such details.
- Instead, a vowel shift and slight semantic shift from similarly-structured adverb *mukumuku* ("thickly, in a billowing or bulging manner"), first [cited in the KDJ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%80%E3%81%8F%E3%82%80%E3%81%8F-641167#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) to a text from 1254.
  *Mukumuku* is limited to soft contexts, things like cotton batting or clouds or smoke.  However, here we do have nearly the same word, with a similar "bulging" sense.  There is at least one other example of a reduplicative adverb pair with one ending in *-u* and the other in *-i*, specifically *kurukuru* ↔ *kurikuri*, of overlapping but not identical meanings.  The pair *sukusuku* ↔ *sukisuki* also have close senses and may be related, demonstrating a similar structure.

#### Tentative conclusion about the derivation

While I cannot find anything definitively stating when the "muscular" sense arose, I suspect it is significantly older than contact between Japanese speakers and German speakers, and indeed possibly older than the German word *Mucki* itself.  As others have noted, this Japanese word is also much older than emoji.

Comment: I had considered including むくむく and くるくる・くりくり in my answer but I honestly thought it was pure speculation to do so. With so few examples of analogous phonotactic vowel shifts, I think it's more likely to be coincidence than a linguistic phenomenon. But that is also speculation.

Comment: You are saying that it cannot come from German "mucki", since the word is older in Japanese. But, at the same time you are saying that it meant something completely different back then in Japanese. This does not exclude the possibility that the Japanese only started using the word in the sense of muscular after hearing it from the Germans.

Comment: @kandyman -- We know that vowel shifting is a word-formation mechanic in Japanese (at least historically, if not currently). We know that there are reduplicative adverb pairs differing only between //-u// and //-i//, where those pairs appear to also have semantic overlap, and seem to be likely cognates. From that, we have an analogy for how むきむき might be related to むくむく. But as you note, this is speculation. Without more textual evidence in the historical record, there's not much we can say with any certainty about むきむき with the "muscular" sense, so indeed, we are left with speculation.

Comment: @a20, no, we cannot entirely rule out the possibility of German influence.  However, as I tried to express above, I find the likelihood of any German derivation to be quite low, particularly given the existence of almost-synonym むくむく from nearly 800 years ago.  Barring more textual evidence, we cannot, definitively, say much about むきむき with the "muscular" sense.

Comment: Is 向き向き really related? 青空文庫 has no instance of 向き向き/剥き剥き/むきむき/ムキムキ in the sense of "muscular". There are many examples of ムキムキ in this sense in BCCWJ (mostly in katakana, a few in hiragana). There is a word ムチムチ, which has a related meaning. These may suggest ムキムキ came into use in the last 50 years or so independently of 向き向き. (And if 向き向き and ムキムキ were etymologically related, why is there no dictionary that mentions this interesting fact?)

Comment: @naruto, re: relatedness between 向き向き and むきむき・ムキムキ ("muscular"), the textual evidence I've been able to evaluate so far is unclear, and I haven't found any dictionaries explaining this, as I mentioned above. Interesting re: BCCWJ; looks like [it only covers texts from 1970 forward](https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/search_form). Any similar sites that include older texts? I also noted むちむち, but the //-tɕ-// ↔ //-k-// shift seemed too wide a gap for any derivational relationship, given the shallow time depth.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I checked 青空文庫全文検索 (mainly <1950), BCCWJ (>=1970) and ヨミダスパーソナル (news articles, 1874-1989). ヨミダス had nothing interesting, which was not surprising because ムキムキ is more or less slangy. 青空全文 has 14 examples of ムチムチ/むちむち, so it's probably older than ムキムキ, and similar mimetic words tends to have similar meanings. Anyhow, to me, it's hard to believe there is a link between 向き向き and ムキムキ unless there is an evidence.

Comment: @naruto, thank you, I'll rework later. Also, re: むちむち, [the KDJ entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%80%E3%81%A1%E3%82%80%E3%81%A1-641916#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) lists four senses under a single entry, suggesting shared derivation, first citation 1731, but first mention of any "muscular" sense only in 1947. That said, sense 4 「ある感情などが、勢いよく、力強くわき出るさま」 makes me think of むきになる, which could be a clue.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi in certain 東北 dialects, き can be pronounced similarly to ち. "キの発音に特徴があります。他の地域の人には，キｽまたはチｼに聞こえることが多いと言われています。". Also, the words きらきら and ちらちら have similar meanings when referring to light, but I have no idea about their respective etymology.
https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/publication/catalogue/onomatopoeia/files/onomatopeia_5.pdf

Comment: @a20, interesting -- I lived in Morioka some years ago, and never heard き as ち.  Perhaps more aspirated than an English speaker's //ki// pronunciation, but not so affricated as to become //tɕi//.  The //k// ↔ //tɕ// equivalence is definitely a feature much further southwest, in Okinawa, but I'm not familiar with it in the northeast.  The ちらちら core meaning is something like "flutteringly", and my understanding has been that the "light"-related sense was an extension from this, rather than cognacy with きらきら.  See also [Kotobank's KDJ entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/ちらちら-569654) at bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is an interesting observation, it is unlikely to be anything more than a coincidence. There is an established theoretical body of literature on Japanese sound symbolism which takes into account things like phonoaesthetics. It seems that some onomatopoeic forms use particular combinations of consonants and vowels to convey a range of related concepts. It is most likely to be derived from such linguistic phenomenon. According to Tranter in "The Languages of Japan and Korea", most of these words are not derivable from content words anyway. In English, you see a similar thing in words like 'glow', 'glisten', 'glitter', 'glimmer', etc, which all convey something to do with light/reflection.

Also, although icons such as the ones you mentioned are ubiquitous these days, they weren't prevalent before the huge explosion in the spread of mobile devices in the last 15 years, whereas words like ムキムキ were.

Despite that, there is no reason to not use it as a visual pun :)

Comment: more than just English: "glühen", "glitzern", "glitzern", "glimern", "glitzern"  I wonder how many Indo-European languages are the same.

Comment: many: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%C7%B5%CA%B0elh%E2%82%83-

Comment: @devio, see also PIE root [***ǵʰley-**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/ǵʰley-) ("to shine").  Notably, all daughter languages appear to be along the northern and western edges of the PIE range (Germanic and Celtic).